# Don't include current user in Pluck array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, forms

I have a form where a user can CRUD a task and assign it to another user via the form. I currently am using the *pluck* method to get the full array of users. Naturally, I want to exclude the current user from this list.

My current code in task > _form.html.erb is as follows:

```
<%= f.select :assignee, User.pluck(:email), :prompt => "Select one" %>
```

It's difficult to figure out what to do since User.pluck(:email) provides a full array that is hard to exclude values from. Appreciate any suggestions, ideally that can be done in this field rather than in the controller.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using `where` and passing conditions to exclude the `current_user`

```
<%= f.select :assignee, User.where("id <> ?", current_user.id).pluck(:email), :prompt => "Select one" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add a where condition:

```
<%= f.select :assignee, User.where('id != ?', current_user.id).pluck(:email), :prompt => "Select one" %>
```